# What is "deferred processing"? Is it possible to explain it in the context of how Android uses it?

Tags: android, concept

I've been going through "Appinventor for Android" by Jason Tyler and I came across this:

> "Deferred processing means that a series of blocks are executed and
>   then there is a time in the processing of the blocks where the device
>   can receive input or events from the user and catch up."

I've searched on other sources but they doesn't explain it in the context of Android.

Can someone please explain it with an example on how android uses this? Thank you!

Comment: Android doesn't use it. App Inventor apparently does.

Comment: "Who process the blocks?" -- App Inventor. Android does not have a concept of "blocks". "If AppInventor does, how does receiving input on Android interrupt AppInventor?" -- it doesn't, in all likelihood. Android does not "interrupt" apps when user input occurs. It calls methods on actvities and widgets when user input occurs. How App Inventor is translating its blocks metaphor to Java code that implements an Android app, I cannot say.